# Problem setting java.util.logging.config.file property in Eclipse's 'VM arguments' section

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, configuration

I'm trying to pass `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/my/logging.properties` so that I can configure my loggers using the properties file. Under 'Run Configurations' I select my project and go to the 'Arguments' tab. In the 'VM Arguments' box, I have `java.util.logging.config.file=${project_loc}/logging.properties`

However, every time I try to run the project using this run configuration, I get this error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/config/file=/Users/hamiltont/Documents/Programming/eclipse-workspace/Tesselation/logging/properties`

I notice that every period has been turned into a slash, and I can't seem to figure out what to do about it! The location is correct for the file (although the file is logging.properties, not logging/properties)

Comment: You're my hero, and I'm a fool. Although it still isn't working totally :( Another 30 minutes of wrestling with java. Toss that in the answer field and I'll accept it

Comment: Woo! now it was just a tiny issue with the properties file! I can work!

Comment: Not a problem.  It is easy to miss the little things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the -D missing from your run configuration?